# why <pre> tag displaying automatically

Tags: php, html

Question:

The following HTML code is displaying the text "

```
"tags automatic. What is wrong with the code? How can it be fixed?
```

`<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   tets
</body>
</html>`

Comment: In the linked duplicate you asked **exactly** this question but have appeared to take no notice of the comments left. The code (?) that you have shown is irrelevant and does not produce the `pre` tags. The code that **does** generate that markup remains a mystery to all except you - nobody else can identify this issue without studying ( in depth most likely) your code and you have not shared that so....

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code doesn't have problem but if the `<pre>` tag displaying automatically whithout you write it in your code, maybe the problem is for this:

1. Server-side code
2. Your CSS & JS file
3. If you use CMS maybe the problem is for that